# Complex joins on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join

there are two table A and B. select all from A but if exists in B select records from B not A. so results should have records from A(not that exists on B) + B(only that matched on A)

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

> records from A(not that exists on B) + B(only that matched on A)

Assuming A and B have the same structures, something like that:

```
(select * from A
  EXCEPT
 select * from B) -- A records that don't exist in B
UNION             -- Plus
( select * from B
   INTERSECT
  select * from A)  -- B records that exist in A
```